# Sidebar Structure for Repositories and Projects

Tags: github, github-for-windows, github-desktop

I use Github for Desktop on Windows 10.

On the download page (https://desktop.github.com/) there is an image showing the sidebar with headline captions (GitHub, Other):

[image]

I use the Client with Bitbucket and therefore I have multiple projects each containing several repositories.

What I want to achieve is this:

[image]

Is this possible? A tree-structure-outline would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Since Oct. 2016, [GitHub Desktop was rewritten, based on Electron](https://blog.github.com/2017-09-19-announcing-github-desktop-1-0/).

However, the list of repos is unchanged (GitHub Desktop 1.1, March 2018):

[image: repos]

You can filter them, but not organize them in a tree-like structure.